# Vimperator - Bash - can't use alias

Tags: firefox, shell, bash

I am using the Firefox plugin Vimperator that simulates vim like behaviour. However, i want to use some Bash commands i specified in my ~/.bashrc.
For example, i have todo.txt.sh bound to an alias 't' so that i can simply type 't add remberToDoThis' to add a task.
It would we wonderful to have the ability to add tasks from within Vimperator by typing

:!t add task

However, this is the message i get:
:!t add task
/bin/bash: t command not found
shell returned 127

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your try, but actually i found out a way:

just do the following in vimperator:

:set shell=/bin/bash
:set shellcmdflag=-ic

by default the shellcmdflag option is only "-c" by adding i we are telling the bash to be interactively, allowing to execute my aliases from the .bashrc

After doing this, it finally works. My aliases are recognized and are working, besides the fist line always telling me no job control available but i can live with that

Comment: You may be able to use `shellcmdflag=-imc` to enable job control (and eliminate the message).

Answer (score 0):

Vimperator has no knowledge of bash aliases, so you have to call your script directly.

You can however define an abbreviation like:

```
:cabbr tt !todo.txt.sh
```

so you can type: `:tt`<kbd>space</kbd> and have it expanded to `!todo.txt.sh`.